# Toggle between maptype id dynamically

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps api v3.. I can load an layer that is generated by my .NET code. I am displaying that custom layer on the map..
Can i able to toggle between these Map types ?? If so How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it..
Just you have to write the code

```
map.setMapTypeId("yourmaptypeid");
```

Comment: Ok..But Can i able to toggle between the my custom image map and google map.??

Comment: Yes you can... For example ur custom image map has maptypeid of 'Customid' then you can write like this
 map.setMapTypeId(Customid); --> For UrCustomImageMap
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE); --> For Satellite

Comment: Its ok..Thank you @Pravin Kumar